# How to use make scp prompt for password when executed with Plink

Tags: batch-file, ssh, scp, plink

I want to write a batch script which will run `scp` command in remote server, using Plink from my Windows.

The code is:

```
plink.exe -ssh 10.168.5.15 -l username -pw passwd scp abc.txt xuser@10.168.10.108:/home
```

What I'm expecting is a prompt for password for the remote machine to where I'm coping file in my batch window. When I run above code my batch window shows, *"Permission Denied, please try again"* three times and *"lost connection"* message. I also tried `scp` with `PasswordAuthentication=yes` and `BatchMode=yes` but no use.

And I'm sure that Plink is interactive.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: "i'm expecting is a promp for asking password " Maybe dropping option ```-pw passwd``` ? In Linux ```ssh``` offers you a highly verbose mode by adding option ```-v``` or ```-vv```. Check if plink offers something like that and see what the log messsages say. Check that you're giving the right username and the right password. Check that that user has indeed an account and/or that it is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The PLink runs the command (`scp`) in a non-interactive session by default. The `scp` won't even prompt for password in the non-interactive session for security reasons.

Use the `-t` switch to force the interactive session.

```
plink.exe -t -ssh 10.168.5.15 ...
```

---

Quoting section [3.8.3.12](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty) of PuTTY/Plink manual:

> **3.8.3.12 `-t` and `-T`: control pseudo-terminal allocation**
>
> The `-t` option ensures PuTTY attempts to allocate a pseudo-terminal at the server, and `-T` stops it from allocating one. These options are only meaningful if you are using SSH.
>
> These options are equivalent to the ‘Don't allocate a pseudo-terminal’ checkbox in the SSH panel of the PuTTY configuration box (see [section 4.24.1](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-pty)).

Comment: Thanks a lot.It fixed the problem!!